How to change the appearance of file object?
Sometimes the file path is too long, and it's really inconvenient to open the file by clicking the ">>" button on the right.
Is it able to modify the appearance of file object by changing e.g. stylesheet?
For example, if the file path is longer than some threshold width, it is better to show this file object as File[".../abc/"] so that one can easily click the ">>" button to open.


File is displayed as TemplateBox[..., "FileArgument"], and you can change its appearance by modifying your style definitions. Please see the two related questions:

How to change the background color of DateObject?
How to change the color scheme of DifferentialRoot and DifferenceRoot outputs?

In the example below, I am using FileNameTake[..., -1] to display only the filename. You can modify this function to achieve whatever formatting you want.
displayFunctionDefault = DisplayFunction /. (TemplateBoxOptions /. 
     CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "FileArgument"}]);

displayFunction = displayFunctionDefault /. StyleBox[#1, opt___] :>
    DynamicBox@StyleBox[FileNameTake[ToExpression[#1], -1], opt];

SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
     Cell[StyleData["FileArgument"], 
      TemplateBoxOptions -> {DisplayFunction -> displayFunction}]}]];


Alternatively, you can put the button in front of the filename:
displayFunction = displayFunctionDefault /. 
   GridBox[{{file_, button_}}, opts__] :> GridBox[{{button, file}}, opts];

SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
     Cell[StyleData["FileArgument"], 
      TemplateBoxOptions -> {DisplayFunction -> displayFunction}]}]];



Thx! Exactly what I need!
